# Create new blank XAML includes "Windows" namespace

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm working with VS 2013 (Update 4) and xamarin integration. I created a new Xamarin.Forms Shared Project and added a new BlankPage.xaml to the shared project. But when I do so I get following Errors:

[image]

In this screenshot you can see that VS added the "Windows" namespace by default.
I have not written any code yet. It's a new Solution. Xamarin is up to date.

Does anyone of you heard about that issue? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I made was that I created the wrong project type.
The right one calls `Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared)`.